# How to solve parse issues when a CSV has a field content escaped with double quotes

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

The input is received from a Salesforce Bulk API query.

INPUT

```
"RecordTypeId","Name","Description"
"AAA","Talent 2022 - Skills Renewal - ABC","DF - 14/03 - Monty affirmed that the ""mastercard approach"" would best fit in this situation. I will connect (abc, def, ghi) and the confirm booking tomorrow (15/03)"
```

SCRIPT:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv separator=",", ignoreEmptyLine=false, quoteValues=true, quoteHeader=true, lineSeparator="\r\n"
---
payload
```

OUTPUT:

```
"RecordTypeId","Name","Description"
"AAA","Talent 2022 - Skills Renewal - ABC","DF - 14/03 - Monty affirmed that the , def, ghi) and the confirm booking tomorrow (15/03)"
```

Expected OUTPUT:
The column description has " and , in it and therefore some description content is getting lost and some is getting shifted to different columns. I need entire description value in one column

Comment: A suggestion. Use tripple backtick '\`' for formatting multi line snippets (like your csv and dataweave). Just wrap the csv and dw part aroung  tripple backtick  `\`\`\``. Currently the question is very confusing because of formatting

Comment: Hi @HarshankBansal
Thank you for the solution. It is working fine in dw editor but not in studio. Any leads on that please ?

Comment: What is the issue
 that you are facing during that?

Comment: @HarshankBansal Thank you for solution. This is removed from scope for next 2 weeks. I will try again after that and post its update here

Comment: If your issue has changed significantly then post a new question.

Comment: @HarshankBansal I have started testing again. Is there a way to wrap description field entries ?

Comment: @aled issue is same. Trying to fix description field. However the solution provided by Harshank has some what helped in getting close to the fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your payload is using `"` as escape character. By default DataWeave expects `\` as the escape character for CSV, so you will need to specify the escape character explicitly while reading your input, after which DataWeave should be able to read the completely description as a single value.

For example the below DataWeave shows how you can use the `input` derivative to read your csv correctly. I do not know what exactly is your expected output so I am just giving an example that writes the value of description as text

```js
%dw 2.0
input payload application/csv escape='"'
output text
---
payload[0].Description
```

The output of this will is

```
DF - 14/03 - Monty affirmed that the "mastercard approach" would best fit in this situation. I will connect (abc, def, ghi) and the confirm booking tomorrow (15/03)
```

Comment: Using input as a directive is not documented.

Comment: @aled it is mentioned in the documentation itself : https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/1.2/dataweave-reference-documentation#input-directive

Comment: That's for DataWeave 1.0.

Comment: That's annoying. It is been used in other part of docs but there is nothing specific on it. For example in [Streaming](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-streaming#validate-a-script-for-streamed-data-experimental-feature) and [Multiple](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-formats-multipart#source-4) docs

Comment: It is mentioned as a reserved word in DataWeave 2.0 docs.

Comment: Hi Harshank, I have started testing again. Is there a way to wrap description field entries ?

Comment: @RahulSingh if you want to wrap output data fields in doublequotes, you can set quoteValues and quoteHeader to true. These are set to false by default.

Answer (score 1):

The escape character has to be set to a double quote (`"`) for DataWeave to recognize that `""` is an escaped quote and not the end of a string. You can not use replace or any string operation because they are executed after the input is parsed.

You need to configure the reader properties in the [source of that payload](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-formats#set_mime_types). For example in the SFTP or HTTP listeners, or whatever connector or operation reads the CSV. There you can add the outputMimeType attribute and set the input type and its properties. Note that because the flow is in an XML file you need to be mindful of XML escaping also to use double quotes, and also need to escape the double quotes as DataWeave expects it, with a backslash (`\`).

Example:

```js
outputMimeType="application/csv; escape=&quot;\&quot;&quot;"
```

Comment: thank you for the solution. This is out of scope for 2 weeks. I will try post that and update here